# How to connect two kinect v.2 sensor to one computer

Tags: computer-vision, kinect, depth, xbox-one

I'm updating an application which use 3 kinect v1 with sdk 1.8 connected to the same computer.

Actually i am updating my application with kinect v2, to improve the performance of my system. The last version of microsoft sdk 2.0 does not support multi sensor connection.

The only solution that i tried which works is to use three different pc, 
each for kinect v.2, and exchange data through Ethernet connection.

The problem of this solution is that is too expensive.
The minimum specs of kinect 2 require expensive pc, while i was considering to use this solution just with smart small computer like raspberry 2.

My questions are:

1. Do you know any hack solution to provide mulitple kinect v2 sensor connection to the same computer?
2. Do you know any low cost, raspberry likes, solution, which respect the minimum kinect v2 requirements?  (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/purchase/sensor_setup.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you only need the video and depth data, perhaps you could investigate to use https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2

Here I can understand if the maximum framerate could be a bit lower than what you get on an intel i5 system with USB 3.0.

The rest of the high requirements is also necessary for skeleton tracking. So this won't be available then, also as this is not present in the libfreenect2.

Comment: For my application i need just for depth and color data, that's why this driver should be suitable for me. But it doesn't support multi sensor connection, and from what i've understood it looks to be useful to connect kinect to pc with low requirements.

Comment: Where do you find info about multi sensor connection for this freenect2 driver?

Comment: looking at: https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/blob/master/examples/protonect/include/libfreenect2/libfreenect2.hpp I see the methods `enumerateDevices()` and `openDevice(int idx)`. Gives me good hope to open more than 1 device...

Comment: @dinoiama any update on your progress? were you able to get multiple sensors working together on a single pc?

Comment: @pdriegen.. yes i tried the libfreenect2 and i am not been success to build the windows version of this driver. From what i understood this library it is still embrional, and a freeze and release version is not still ready. The only solution seems to use multiple pc connected with lan, but due to high throughput, it is difficult to work with a frame rate of 30fps of the device.